# How to close the FaceTime "picture in picture" app

Tags: facetime

I started FaceTime during a phone call from my iPhone6S . After completing the call the Facetime app is still there in black saying

> This FaceTime call is in Picture in Picture

It is not possible to close the app via swiping.  So how can it be closed?